# Pass AJAX retrieved data to populate HTML click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the following AJAX function to retrieve data from an API. The retrieved data needs to be used in the populateBlocks function to populate various HTML blocks in the form with vehicle data. I am also needing to attach the customer's first name to the function and populate the same HTML blocks. The AJAX function works. You can see what I have so far in action here: http://autolife.granddemo.co.nz/get-quote/. How can I prevent the summary block from displaying before the Get Quote button is clicked?

```
$("#get-rego").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var regoAjax = document.querySelector(".ajax-loader");
addClass(regoAjax, "active");

var plate = document.getElementById("input_2_6").value;

$.post({
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: {
    "action": "get_vehicle",
    "plate": plate,
  },
  "dataType": "json",
  success: function(obj) {
    var response = obj.idh;
    console.log(response);
    removeClass(regoAjax, "active");
    removeClass(vehicleDetails, "gfield_conditionally_hidden");
    var vehicleMake = response.vehicle.make;
    var vehicleModel = response.vehicle.model;
    var vehicleYear = response.vehicle.year_of_manufacture;
    var vehicleColour = response.vehicle.main_colour;
    var vehicleSubModel = response.vehicle.submodel;
    var vehicleBodyStyle = response.vehicle.body_style;
    var vehicleWofExpiry = response.vehicle.expiry_date_of_last_successful_wof;
    var vehicleRegoExpiry = response.vehicle.date_of_last_registration;

    var vehicleDataSummaryOutput = "<div class=\"summary\">" +
      "<ul>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Make:</span> " + titleCase(vehicleMake) + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Model:</span> " + titleCase(vehicleModel) + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Year:</span> " + vehicleYear + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Colour:</span> " + vehicleColour + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Submodel:</span> " + titleCase(vehicleSubModel) + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Body Style:</span> " + vehicleBodyStyle + "</li>" +
      "</ul>" +
      "</div>";

    document.querySelector(".vehicle-details").innerHTML = vehicleDataSummaryOutput;
    populateSummaryBlocks(response.vehicle);
  }
  });
});

function populateSummaryBlocks(vehicle) {
  var vehicleMake = vehicle.make;
  var vehicleModel = vehicle.model;
  var customerName = document.querySelector("input_2_46_3").value;

  document.body.querySelector(".vehicle-make-text").innerHTML = vehicleMake;
  document.body.querySelector(".vehicle-model-text").innerHTML = vehicleModel;
}
document.querySelector("#choice_2_121_1").addEventListener("change", populateSummaryBlocks, false);
```

Comment: Set it to `display: none` before you load the page. Change `display: none` to `display: block` after you successfully received the data you needed. Can it be this easy or did I miss anything?

Comment: @RMo I have taken your suggestion and re-worked my functions to add some display classes after all of the required data has been entered and the "Get Quote" button is clicked. Now I just need to figure out how to keep certain HTML blocks populated after the form refreshes when there are errors. Any tips?